# Problems with escaped characters in JSON string

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, facebook

I have a JSON-string where I know where the problem is, I just can't figure out what to do. I have looked up the "forbidden characters" in a JSON-string but it just doesn't work.
When you run the show-method for FBStreamDialog for iPhone a view comes up with how it's going to look like when it's finally posted on the wall.

This happends when the "description"-property in my JSON-string is hard coded like @"Testing". But as soon as I add the text fetched from a data source which looks like this, it doesn't work:

```
            "description":"

    LIVE: Uk's No:1 Reggae Singer Bitty Mclean + Joey Fever, Sthlms No:1 Reggae Voice.

        DJs
        Deejay Flash & Micke Goulos + Mc Fabulous G.

        The Vinyl Bar
        Up...

"
```

**Note:** I only show the "description"-property of the JSON-string, because there is where the problem is.

So what I tried to do was, as I've explained before, to add the string "Testing" in the "description"-property. This worked. But I wanted to have the data source property of "description", of course. So I tried to replace all the characters that isn't a letter with this code:

```
shortString = [shortString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"och"];
shortString = [shortString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"plus"];
shortString = [shortString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"komma"];
shortString = [shortString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"apostrof"];
shortString = [shortString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"colon"];
```

The output of that is:

```
    "description":"LIVEcolon Ukapostrofs Nocolon1 Reggae Singer Bitty Mclean plus Joey Feverkomma Sthlms Nocolon1 Reggae Voice.

DJs
Deejay Flash och Micke Goulos plus Mc Fabulous G.

The Vinyl Bar
Up...
```

Which looks like a approvable JSON string?

But apparently not, because the facebook view never shows how it's going to look if I use the data source "description"-property. It just shows the text box "What's on your mind".

This is driving me crazy.

Comment: I'm desperate, which shows. Just tried to replace the number "1"... Oh my god... ;)

Comment: I can add that I don't get an error message at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally!

I understand why you didn't answer this question. How could you know that facebook connect doesn't allow **\n** in their StreamDialog's. Not for iPhone anyway.

So the solution was to *replace \n with a whitespace* or whatever you want.

Comment: I thought I had the same escaping problem, but turns out I worked after I removed the \n as well. Thanks for posting the solution